# How to increase camara view clearity in CWAC Camera Library?

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

When i am capture image from my mobile native app, image size is 2MB, but when capture by,  CWAC Camera Library demo, it resolution is very low size is 400kb, Why this happen ?

Please suggiest me proper solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it resolution is very low size is 400kb

Resolution and file size are not the same thing. Resolution refers to the number of pixels in each direction (e.g., 1920x1080). File size is measured in KB and will depend on a number of factors, such as the resolution and the compression level.

> Please suggiest me proper solution

The "proper solution" is for you to compare resolutions, rather than comparing file sizes.

I would also recommend that you not use the library, as I will need to completely rewrite it (due to `android.hardware.Camera` being deprecated).

If you wish to continue using the library, you will need to read [the instructions for controlling picture sizes](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#controlling-picture-sizes), setting up a custom `CameraHost` that returns a valid picture resolution via `getPictureSize()`.

Comment: is there any why to i can directly increase CamaraView ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati: I have no idea what you mean by this, sorry.